# Daily updates from SQL server to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server, scheduled-tasks

I'm building an e-commerce website, using PHP (Codeigniter) and MySQL.

The products table has a stock field, which needs to be updated daily (perhaps several times a day). The source for these updates is a local SQL Server table (used by SAP B1).

I should say I have no way of knowing which items where changed, so I have to go over the whole products table (tens of thousands lines).

This is how I thought I'd do it:

1. Issue a scheduled query on the SQL Server, to create a text file of
   the item code and stock level. (done)
2. Issue a scheduled ftp command to upload that text file onto the web server (done)
3. Parse the uploaded text file using codeigniter function, to create an array to be used for batch update (haven't done, but seems easy enough).

My questions are:

1. Am I going in the right direction here? Is there a better way to do it? Am I risking performance issues here? (I mean, will this job interfere with the performance of my website? How long will it take to run, for a several thousand lines?)
2. How do I schedule the codeigniter function (item 3 above)? Just use any scheduler on any local machine that would call my php function via its url (mywebsite.com/my_update_function)?

Comment: I guess there might be atleast one filed in the SQL Server table when the record was changed, And when you truncate the whole table in your MySQL database, then users won't be able to see any products, which will be embarrassing for an e-commerce website. 

So  what my suggestion is just create a PHP code in your server that create a temporary table with the records updated from last updatation in your SQL server (keep a table row in a settings table in your MySQL database so that you can check against SQL server).

and del the records in your mysql tab and ins em or even you can updt them.

Comment: and add a scheduler on php file. I am not sure about code Igniter, but you can do it indivually, no need to have that interface at all.

Answer (score 0):

We can use triggers directly on your SAP B1 table for your case..It may solve your problem. 
But there is a problem with SAP B1. if we use Triggers on system tables or on UDT of SAP B1 there will be a problem while upgrading SAP B1 to higher levels. 
take care of that and proceed.